# A property of the polar decomposition of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose that $T$ be an operator on Hilbert space $H$. By the polar decomposition theorem of  functional analysis we have:

Let $T$ be an operator on Hilbert space $H$. Then there exists a partial isometry $U$ such that $T=U|T|$, where $|T|={(T^*T)}^\frac{1}{2}$, and $N(U) = N(|T|)$ and $U^* U|T|=|T|$.

Note that with the condition $N(U) = N(|T|)$ we can show that such polar decomosition is unique.

Now I want to show that if $T^2 =I$ then $U^2 =I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T^2=I$, you have $T^{-1}=T$. From $T=U|T|$, we get $U=T|T|^{-1}$. Then 
$$
|T|^{-1}=(T^*T)^{-1/2}=[(T^*T)^{-1}]^{1/2}=[T^{-1}{T^{-1}}^*]^{1/2}=(TT^*)^{1/2}.
$$
Now the key fact is that $T(T^*T)^n=(TT^*)^nT$, and as the square root is a limit of polynomials with no constant term, 
$$
T(T^*T)^{1/2}=(TT^*)^{1/2}T.
$$
Thus
$$
|T|^{-1}T=(TT^*)^{1/2}T=T(T^*T)^{1/2}=T|T|. 
$$
Thus
$$
U^2=T|T|^{-1}T|T|^{-1}=TT|T||T|^{-1}=I. 
$$